# which type is drawable folder exactly?

Tags: android, android-drawable

which type is drawable folder ?
I know drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,
drawable-xxxhdpi and drawable-nodpi. But there is a folder just named drawable.
So which is exactly its kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drawable` directory is actually equivalent to `drawable-mdpi`. This equivalence is to maintain backwards compatibility (early versions of Android did not need to support multiple screen densities).

Commonsware wrote [a good blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html) that mentions the backward compatibility:

> res/drawable/ is a synonym for res/drawable-mdpi/, for backwards compatibility with really old Android apps, written before we had density-specific resources.

Nowadays, it's useful for XML-defined drawables, e.g. shape or [vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#vector-graphics):

> Because one vector drawable can be used on all pixel densities, this file goes in your default drawables directory (you don't need to use density-specific directories):
>
> ```
> res/
>   drawable/
>     ic_android_launcher.xml
> ```